# Hidden Recovery Partition became visible after using GParted on another partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Just used GPartEd for resizing of D: partition, but now the hidden recovery partition became visible in windows explorer which is prone to accidental deletion etc. Any solution to this except gpedit.msc which is not available in windows7 home premium edition?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the 'hidden' flag on that partition within GParted? I'm guessing that's all you really need to do but I've been known to be wrong before.